Migrate to English Language Blog
I have an active eCommerce Blog with around 500 articles on my own language and now planning to translate all the content into English. It currently running on WordPress and want to achieve this with no plugin, nor also multisite.
What in my mind as the option now are:

Translate all the 500 content and put it in a new category /en/ (all the original content will still remain).
Translate all the 500 content and delete all the original and set
the redirection.
Your other better option.....

please help to give suggestion among the option which not hurt SEO and even more boost SEO.
